# linq dynamic query is not populating collection

Tags: silverlight, linq, ria, linqpad

```
private void OnSearchExecute(IQueryable<SurveySearchCriteria> query)
    {
        SurveySearchCriteria ssc=query.Where(a => a.CriteriaString == "LastName").SingleOrDefault();

        string format = ssc.WhereClause;
        string args= string.Format(".{0}(\"{1}\")", SelectedSearchType, EnteredSearchCriteria);

        string returnval = string.Format(format, args);           




        ReadmissionTrackingApplication.Server.Services.SurveysDomainContext _context =
                                new ReadmissionTrackingApplication.Server.Services.SurveysDomainContext();

        EntityQuery<ReadmitPatientList> eq = _context.GetReadmitPatientListByCriteriaQuery(returnval);

       var lo= _context.Load<ReadmitPatientList>(eq);
```

using this code it does not populate my lo.entities. 
I have a feeling its because I am not using a callback, but the query works just fine in linqpad.

returnval= "PatientLastName.Contains(\"test\")" and when i plug it into linqpad it works.

ReadmitPatientList.AsQueryable().Where("PatientLastName.Contains(\"test\")")

here is the domainservice query...

```
public IQueryable<Data.ReadmitPatientList> GetReadmitPatientListByCriteria(string formattedCriteriaString)
        {
            var query = this.ObjectContext.ReadmitPatientList.AsQueryable()
                             .Where(a => a.OriginalAdmitDate >= new DateTime(2010, 01, 01))
                             .Where(formattedCriteriaString);

            return query;

        }
```

My question is why is this working in linqpad but not in my code. I am using silverlight, so it could be because of no callback. This is my first major foray into webbasede programming so I am still getting used to all the intricacies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a callback issue. I refactored my code so that it implemented call back functionality and cleaned up the Domainservice calls and now it works.

CLIENT SERVICE:

```
public void getReadmitPatientList(System.Action<ICollection<ReadmitPatientList>> callback, string searchCriteria)
        {
            var q = _context.GetReadmitPatientListByCriteriaQuery(searchCriteria);
            _context.Load<ReadmitPatientList>(q, OnReamitPatientListLoaded, callback);
        }

        public void getReadmitPatientList(System.Action<ICollection<ReadmitPatientList>> callback, int days)
        {
            DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Today;

            DateTime entryDate = CurrentDate.AddDays(-days);

            var q = _context.GetReadmitPatientListQuery().Where(a => a.OriginalAdmitDate >= entryDate);
            _context.Load<ReadmitPatientList>(q, OnReamitPatientListLoaded, callback);

        }

        public void OnReamitPatientListLoaded(LoadOperation<ReadmitPatientList> lo)
        {
            if (!lo.HasError)
            {
                ICollection<ReadmitPatientList> q = new ObservableCollection<ReadmitPatientList>(lo.Entities);
                var action = (Action<ICollection<ReadmitPatientList>>)lo.UserState;
                action.Invoke(q);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{1}{0}{2}", Environment.NewLine, lo.Error.Message, lo.Error.InnerException));

                lo.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            }
        }
```

DOMAIN SERVICE:

```
 public IQueryable<Data.ReadmitPatientList> GetReadmitPatientListByCriteria(string formattedCriteriaString)
    {
        var query = this.ObjectContext.ReadmitPatientList.AsQueryable()
                         .Where(a => a.OriginalAdmitDate >= new DateTime(2010, 01, 01))
                         .Where(formattedCriteriaString);

        return query;

    }
```